# How to get a list of files that match some pattern?

Tags: linux, unix, filenames, vim

How to get a list of files that match some pattern if filenames may contain `\n` character?

**Update**: I want solution in pure vimscript, so that it will depend on nothing but vim.

**Update2**:

## Expected output of glob function

Consider the following script:

```
:!touch /test ; mkdir /test$'\n' ; touch /test$'\n'/test
:echo glob('/**/test')
/test
/test
/test
```

That is the output of `glob` function. I want it be the following:

```
:echo NewGlob('/**/test')
['/test', '/test
/test']
```

Comment: I haven't found anything in the vim docs that would provide what you want, nor any directory-listing tools short of :browse. But vim is commonly built to link against Perl, Python, or Ruby to provide more libraries/functionality. Would this be alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to write the following function that returns just the same results as python's os.listdir:

```
    function s:globdir(directory, ...)
        return split(glob(escape(a:directory.g:os#pathSeparator, '`*[]\').
                    \     get(a:000, 0, '*')),
                    \"\n", 1)
    endfunction
    function s:GetDirContents(directory)
        let dirlist = s:globdir(a:directory)+s:globdir(a:directory, '.*')
        let nlnum=len(split(a:directory, "\n", 1))-1
        let r=[]
        let i=0
        let addfragment=""
        for directory in dirlist
            if i<nlnum
                let i+=1
                let addfragment=directory."\n"
                continue
            else
                let directory=addfragment.directory
                let i=0
                let addfragment=""
            endif
            let tail=fnamemodify(directory, ':t')
            if tail==#'.' || tail==#'..'
                continue
            endif
            if directory[0]!=#'/'
                let r[-1].="\n".directory
            else
                call add(r, tail)
            endif
        endfor
        return r
    endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try using `ls` with `-b` option. check the man page

Comment: I can also use `find -print0`, but I can't rely on existence of `ls` or `find`. And `ls -Q` is more suitable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
:echo split( glob("pattern", '.'), "\r")
```

If you want the pattern to match files containing `\n` exclusively, use `"*\n*"`.

---

EDIT:

I see, the character you use in the filename is the same as the one used by `glob()` to distinguish results. As a consequence, we can't rely of `glob()`.
ghostdog74 gave a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123590/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-that-match-some-pattern/3123859#3123859) then:

```
:echo split( system('ls -1bd test*'), "\n")
```

Of course, this is not portable. But I do not really call this the general case -- I never see this kind of names. If `glob()` cannot handle this general case, then `glob()` must be fixed.

May be you can try with embedded python or ruby as arnold suggested. But that isn't portable either.

Comment: No, I want to construct a generic `glob` function that will take any pattern that glob accepts (excluding `glob("\x60command\x60")`) and return a list of files, that all match specified pattern and all exist. Since the function is generic, I must consider the case when there is LF in filename. Now I can only do that thing: convert glob pattern into string pattern, split glob on LF and join until I get a unique filename that both matches this string pattern and exists (no code, only an idea that I do not like).

Comment: I fail to understand the problem. Could you elaborate your need? i.e. the "newglobfunction" call + the expected output?

Comment: @Luc, glob can't really be "fixed" -- it is specified to return a string with new-line delimiters between filenames. A NewGlob function could of course have a different specification to return an array, just as ZyX wants. (I'm in fact surprised that vim's glob throws away useful information just for some convenience; an array of filenames can easily be turned into a nl or space delimited string, but the reverse is very difficult.)

Comment: |List|s were not implemented at the time `glob()` was added to vim. So indeed, we'd need a `globreturnedaslist()` function to avoid any regression.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but bounty ends in 2 hours and this is the best answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this python program. It will match files like `abc\n1`, `abc\n2abc` etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, re
dirlist = os.listdir('.')
pattern = 'abc\n\\d'
for fname in dirlist:
  if re.search(pattern, fname):
    print fname.replace('\n', '\\n')
```

It will replace line end ('`\n`') characters with "`\n`" string for clarity.